# Modify views of a UI Router template

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to inject default data into a `ui-view` template.

```
$stateProvider.state('foo', {
  template: '<div ui-view=bar></div>',
  abstract: true,
  views: {
    bar: {
      template: 'test'
    }
  }
});

$stateProvider.state('foo.whiz', {
  // ...
});
```

This example doesn't work, but I hope it's enough to show you what I mean. So what I'm basically trying to do is, when I enter the state `foo.whiz`, which has a parent of `foo`, I'd like `foo` to inject default data into the `bar` `ui-view`. Currently it only seems you can populate named views via the child state (`bar@foo`)? How can I, essentially, initialize data via the route object?

Answer (score 0):

I would say, there are 4 ways *(maybe more)* how to pass some stuff from child to parent. There is [a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Tr8qjd7y2C6NOifclBKi?p=preview).

Let's have these anchors/targets in the index.html:

```
<div ui-view="title"></div>
<div ui-view="scopeInheritance"></div>
<div ui-view="factory"></div>
<div ui-view="content"></div>
```

And this would be the common def of parent state 'foo'

```
.state('foo', {
    url: '/foo',
    views: {
      'title' : { template: '<h3>foo - parent state title</h3>',},
      'scopeInheritance' : 
      { 
        template: '<h3 ui-view="inheritance">{{parentModel.greeting}}</h3>',
        controller: 'parentCtrl',
      },
      'factory' : { template: '<h3>{{dataHolder.message}}</h3>',},
      'content' : {
        template: '<div >Content of foo (parent) <ui-view /></div>',
      },
    },
  })
```

**I. child view replaces parent view completely**

In this case, we will define different content for the view 'title' in our child state:

```
.state('foo.whiz', {
    views: {
      'title@' : { 
        template: '<h3>{{resolved}} - child state title</h3>',
        controller : 'titleCtrl',
        resolve : { resolvedData : function() { return "whiz"; }, },
      },
    ...
```

So, we are using [Absolute Names](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views#view-names---relative-vs-absolute-names) 'title@' to place our view into root template.

**II. scope inheritance, child can fill properties of parents `$scope.parentModel` reference**

```
.state('foo.whiz', {
    views: {
      'inheritance' :  
      { 
        controller: 'childCtrl',
      },
      ...
```

Here we declare some **model** in parent $scope, and due to [Scope Inheritance by View Hierarchy Only](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views#scope-inheritance-by-view-hierarchy-only) we can change these values in a child:

```
// parent declares model
.controller('parentCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.parentModel = { greeting : "Parent greets"};
  ...

// child changes value and does clean up
.controller('childCtrl', function($scope){
  var remember = $scope.parentModel.greeting;
  $scope.parentModel.greeting = "Child greets"
  $scope.$on("$destroy", function (){$scope.parentModel.greeting = remember;});
  ...
```

**III. factory as data holder**

Simply let's inject some singleton, in angular world service/factory, as a holder of data into `$rootScope`

```
// singleton
.factory('dataHolder', function(){
  return {};
});

// available everywhere
app.run(
  ['$rootScope', 'dataHolder',
    function($rootScope, dataHolder) {
      $rootScope.dataHolder = dataHolder;
    ...

// child can assign these, while parent will render them
.controller('childCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.dataHolder.message = "Child sent message"
```

Check that all [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Tr8qjd7y2C6NOifclBKi?p=preview)

**IV. child view is nested in parent:**

the most typical with `UI-Router`

```
// the anchor is inside of the parents view
.state('foo', {
    views: {
      'content' : {                              // the anchor for child
        template: '<div >Content of foo (parent) <ui-view /></div>',
      },
  ...

// child inject directily into parent

.state('foo.whiz', {
    views: {
      '' : {
        template: '<h4>Content of whiz (Child)</h4>',
      },
    ...
```

These are the basic ways how to pass data/view/messages with `UI-Router` *(skipping the eventing system of angular at all)*